# collectstatic, eError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: deployment, digital-ocean, wagtail

I try to deploy a wagtail dev project to digitalocean. Once I run the on the server the command:

python manage.py collectstatic --settings=mysite.settings.production

I get the following error message

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(",")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I follow a commands from the tutorial
[learnwagtail deploy to DO](https://learnwagtail.com/launch-your-wagtail-website-digital-ocean-ubuntu-18/)

I tried different type of combinations, with (',') and without as a split.
combination of IP/*/ or without.
I then tried on an empty wagtail project, the result is the same.

Any return/help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line shown in the error message:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(",")
```

is something you (or someone else...) placed in your settings file at some point, to tell it that rather than ALLOWED_HOSTS being directly defined in the settings, it should be picked up from the DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS system variable. The tutorial you linked to does not account for this setup.

If this setup is something you want to keep, then you'll need to find out how to set environment variables on DigitalOcean - it'll probably be the same way that the tutorial sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. Otherwise, you should find and remove this line, and just leave behind one that sets ALLOWED_HOSTS directly:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.example.com']
```

Answer (score 2):

If your environment file is set correctly, following will solve the problem :

Environment:

```
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
```

Settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS', '').split()
```

Answer (score 1):

You better learn about the basic settings of the Django settings module/s, the error above is indicating that you didn't set the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting to any values, if you are just testing things, you'd set it to `["*"]`, otherwise, you would set to the hostnames that you are hosting on this project/server, something like:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['domainname.com', 'domain2.net', 'www.domain.com']
```

only, in this case, python can find items and apply the split method on them, of course when there are no items in the setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS` it means that sets to None and the `NoneType` object has no attributes at all.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough. I did try with ["*"] alone and with IP, and domainename.com. The problem is the same. You may check [this exampe](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4254). If google results are to be trusted, it's probably linked somehow to the fact that my OS is windows X.

Comment: after I checked the edit you made and the link you shared, it seems there are many possible reasons, without deeply investigating what causes blocks in between the browser's request and the server's response, there is no way to fix anything, if you can follow the suggestion in the link you shared (issue #4254 on wagtail repo), if still you couldn't find any related issues, then kindly share NONE sensitive options in the settings.py(or in your case: mysite.settings.production) I then maybe able to find the cause.. (but please follow the conversation on the issue #4254 before you give-up)

Comment: my production.py is : DEBUG = True 
SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret_key'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

Comment: Regarding the thread. No relavant information for my app. I run cmd.exe /c chcp 1252 with all command, the error message is the same. I don't have the variable DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS

Comment: Issue #4254 is unrelated to this. It's the same Python error (trying to call 'split' on something that should be a string but isn't), but in a totally different area of the code.